# How to pull the numeric values within the div tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, plugins

I have started using javascript from today to create one plugin for firefox. I want to get the numeric value from a webpage which i will further use in a conditional statement. These value collectively create a timer on the webpage.

```
<div class="ureact-countdown_container-dark__3yLv6 ureact-countdown__container__AavqD queue-control-row_countdown__12Ijv">
        <div class="ureact-countdown_digit__3tqK_">
            02
            <span class="ureact-countdown_label__Mebe5">hr</span>
        </div>
        <div class="ureact-countdown_digit__3tqK_">
            35
            <span class="ureact-countdown_label__Mebe5">min</span>
        </div>
        <div class="ureact-countdown_digit__3tqK_">
            43
            <span class="ureact-countdown_label__Mebe5">sec</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

I want the numeric values stored in 3 variables.

I have saw some tutorials where they are using the following code to store the values mentioned within a class. But I have no prior knowledge on javascript.

```
var value = document.getElementsByClassName();
```

But as you can see all have the same class name, so how would i do that.

Any help or references will be appreciated from where I can learn.

Comment: Please paste your code in the question rather than posting a picture of it.

Comment: Please update your question and add the relevant JS code snippet showing us your best  attempt at resolving this yourself, and then explain at what point you're encountering a problem.

Comment: Hi @Nicolas

I have modified the description.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the textContent property of the div elements. So if you select a specific div (e.g. `document.getElementById('print')`), you can alter its textContent property like so `document.getElementById('print').textContent = 5;`

Answer (score 0):

`el.innerHTML.match(/-?\d*\.?\d+/)[0]`

Will pull the first numeric value found in the element. You will need to pull the element into `el`.